# Drop column that starts with

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame that has multiple columns, example:

```
        Prod_A       Prod_B        Prod_C        State         Region
1          1           0             1             1              1
```

I would like to drop all columns that starts with Prod_, (I can't select or drop by name because the data frame has 200 variables)
Is it possible to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for mask and then delete columns with `loc` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('Prod')]
print (df)
   State  Region
1      1       1
```

Answer (score 18):

First, select all columns to be deleted:

```
unwanted = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('Prod_')]
```

The, drop them all:

```
df.drop(unwanted, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure that will work?  unwanted is a boolean Series, and drop will think you're trying to drop columns of True and/or False, no?

Comment: Oops, forgot to select from `df.columns`. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

we can also use negative RegEx:

```
In [269]: df.filter(regex=r'^(?!Prod_).*$')
Out[269]:
   State  Region
1      1       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop all rows where the `path` column starts with `/var`:

```py
df = df[~df['path'].map(lambda x: (str(x).startswith('/var')))]
```

This can be further simplified to:

```py
df = df[~df['path'].str.startswith('/var')]
```

`map`+`lambda` offer more flexibility by allowing to handle raw values as opposed to scalars. In the example below rows will be removed when they start with `/var` or are empty (`nan`, `None`, etc).

```py
df = df[~df['path'].map(lambda x: (str(x).startswith('/var') or not x))]
```

Drop all rows where the `path` column starts with `/var` or `/tmp` (you can also pass a tuple to `startswith`):

```py
df = df[~df['path'].map(lambda x: (str(x).startswith(('/var', '/tmp'))))]
```

<sup>The tilda `~` is used for negation; if you wanted instead to keep all rows starting with `/var` then just remove the `~`.</sup>